# Is it possible to genarrt a list From my assets

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to creat a List like this

```
List<String>
imagePaths = ['assets/images/1.jpg', 'assets/images/2.jpg', 'assets/images/3.jpg'];
```

but in my case I have 90 items ('assets/images/1.jpg'- 'assets/images/90.jpg' is there any way to generate the list for me or do I have to write it down

Comment: since the path is `string` , i think you can crate a loop function to generate the path of image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create with list generate

```
List<String> path = List.generate(5,(int idx) => 'assets/images/$idx.jpg');

print (path);
// result :
[assets/images/0.jpg, assets/images/1.jpg, assets/images/2.jpg, assets/images/3.jpg, assets/images/4.jpg]
```